# Python regex: How to increase only one number in string?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string of following types:

```
a1 = 'images1subimages1/folder100/hello1.png'
a1 = 'images1subimages1 folder100 hello1.png'
a1 = 'images1subimages1folder100hello1.png'
a1 = 'images1b100d1.png'
```

The first Integer of the string is `num0` and we only care about it. We want to increase all occurrence of `num0` by one and keep other numbers the same.

Required:

```
a2 = 'images2subimages2/folder100/hello2.png'
a2 = 'images2subimages2 folder100 hello2.png'
a2 = 'images2subimages2folder100hello2.png'
a2 = 'images2b100d2.png'
```

My attempt:

```
import re
a1 = 'images1subimages1/folder100/hello1.png'

nums = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', a1)))
nums0 = nums[0]
nums_changed = [j+1  if j==nums[0] else j for i,j in enumerate(nums)]
parts = re.findall(r'(\w*\d+)',a1)
for i in range(len(parts)):
  num_parts = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', parts[i])))
  for num_part in num_parts:
    if num_part == nums0:
        parts[i] = parts[i].replace(str(nums0), str(nums0+1))


ans = '/'.join(parts)
ans
```

This has the following result:

```
a1 = 'images1subimages1/folder100/hello1.png' # good
a1 = 'images1subimages1 folder100 hello1.png' # bad
```

Is there a general way to solve the problem using regex in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ì suggest first extracting the first number and then increment all occurrences of this number when it is not enclosed with other digits with `re.sub`:

```
import re
a1 = 'images1subimages1/folder100/hello1.png'
num0_m = re.search(r'\d+', a1)                  # Extract the first chunk of 1+ digits
if num0_m:                                      # If there is a match
    rx = r'(?<!\d){}(?!\d)'.format(num0_m.group())  # Set a regex to match the number when not inside other digits
    print(re.sub(rx, lambda x: str(int(x.group())+1), a1)) # Increment the matched numbers
    # => images2subimages2/folder100/hello2.png
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/GcljbR)

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string on numbers, increment the ones equal to the first one, and rebuild the string:

```
import re


def increment_first(s):
    parts = re.split(r'(\d+)', s)
    nums = list(map(int, parts[1::2]))
    num0 = nums[0]
    nums = [num + (num == num0) for num in nums]
    parts[1::2] = map(str, nums)
    return ''.join(parts)
```

Testing it on your data:

```
tests = ['images1subimages1/folder100/hello1.png',
'images1subimages1 folder100 hello1.png',
'images1subimages1folder100hello1.png',
'images1b100d1.png']

for test in tests:
    print(test, increment_first(test))
```

Output:

```
images1subimages1/folder100/hello1.png images2subimages2/folder100/hello2.png
images1subimages1 folder100 hello1.png images2subimages2 folder100 hello2.png
images1subimages1folder100hello1.png images2subimages2folder100hello2.png
images1b100d1.png images2b100d2.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Alas, I'm not as fast as some of these regex gurus. Here is my solution anyway.

1. Find the first occurrence of a number `re.search(r'\d+', st).group(0)`
2. Substitute the first occurrence where the found number is not preceded or followed by another number `(?<!\d)+' + re.escape(first) + r'(?!\d)+`.

```
import re


def increment_all_of_first_occurring_number(st):
    first = re.search(r'\d+', st).group(0)
    return re.sub(
        r'(?<!\d)+' + re.escape(first) + r'(?!\d)+',
        str(int(first) + 1),
        st
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a1 = 'images1subimages1/folder100/hello1.png'
    a2 = 'images1subimages1 folder100 hello1.png'
    a3 = 'images1subimages1folder100hello1.png'
    a4 = 'images1b100d1.png'

    b1 = 'images10subimages10/folder10101/hello10.png'
    b2 = 'images10subimages10 folder10101 hello10.png'
    b3 = 'images10subimages10folder10101hello10.png'
    b4 = 'images10b10101d10.png'

    print(increment_all_of_first_occurring_number(a1))
    print(increment_all_of_first_occurring_number(a2))
    print(increment_all_of_first_occurring_number(a3))
    print(increment_all_of_first_occurring_number(a4))

    print(increment_all_of_first_occurring_number(b1))
    print(increment_all_of_first_occurring_number(b2))
    print(increment_all_of_first_occurring_number(b3))
    print(increment_all_of_first_occurring_number(b4))
```

*Results*

```
images2subimages2/folder100/hello2.png
images2subimages2 folder100 hello2.png
images2subimages2folder100hello2.png
images2b100d2.png
images11subimages11/folder10101/hello11.png
images11subimages11 folder10101 hello11.png
images11subimages11folder10101hello11.png
images11b10101d11.png
```